# 5 minute comment edit rule supercedes post deletion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, deleted-answers

Not sure if this is by design but if a user deletes their answer then I am still allowed to edit my comments within the 5 minute window.

Not sure if this affects questions as well; I have only tested this on an answer.

Additionally, I can delete my comments from a deleted answer.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be allowed to?  What value is there in explicitly prohibiting it?

Comment: @Servy I don't know. I guess it's just for the sake of consistency. This "feature" invalidates the accompanying `comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews` statement.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: that just relates to the fact that you can't add any more comments. It's not as if anyone can reply to you with more comments if your comments were edited to say something else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess I was just verifying whether or not this is in fact `status-bydesign` or an overlooked discrepancy but clearly it's the former.

Comment: This question makes me regret drawing you a picture of a monkey zeus.

Comment: @Will But, but I love that picture :'-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug. The answer post still exists, the comments still exist, they are still attached to the post.

Posts are *soft-deleted*, and if you are still on the page and can still see the posts, you can still reach those comments. No-one has given the developers reason to prevent editing and deleting of such comments. Moderators can still recover those comments or see their editing history, so any abuse can be managed that way.